# IIS7.5 URL rewrite pboblem on index page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, iis

H,
I've installed wp on IIS7.5 machine. But I'm having error when my permalink setting is line: /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Problem is the index page (root page /) gives 404 error (**EDIT: error is in a wordpress page, not server default page**). But I'm not getting 404 when permalink is default or /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

Site can be seen here: http://marmarabote.innovacube.com/

I've also rewrited urls in web.config like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"
                            negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                            matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: you seem to have solved it

Comment: @edelwater: no I haven't. I just use index.php as home url but this is not very good solution. Since I have an html page that redirects to index.php.

Answer (score 1):

see: [WordPress 3.0.1 on IIS 6 Web Server PermaLink Issues](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/wordpress-3-0-1-on-iis-6-web-server-permalink-issues)